# bootstrap numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to sample with replacement a `base` 2D numpy array with shape of (4,2) by rows, say 10 times. The final output should be a 3D numpy array.

Have tried the code below, it works. But is there a way to do it without the for loop?

```
base=np.array([[20,30],[50,60],[70,80],[10,30]])
print(np.shape(base))
nsample=10
tmp=np.zeros((np.shape(base)[0],np.shape(base)[1],10))
for i in range(nsample):
    id_pick = np.random.choice(np.shape(base)[0], size=(np.shape(base)[0]))
    print(id_pick)
    boot1=base[id_pick,:]
    tmp[:,:,i]=boot1
print(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
m,n = base.shape
idx = np.random.randint(0,m,(m,nsample))
out = base[idx].swapaxes(1,2)
```

Basic idea is that we generate all the possible indices with `np.random.randint` as `idx`. That would an array of shape `(m,nsample)`. We use this array to index into the input array along the first axis. Thus, it selects random rows off `base`. To get the final output with a shape `(m,n,nsample)`, we need to swap last two axes.

Comment: hm.. this looks like should work.. my numpy is out-dated... looks like the `np.take_along_axis` is very new.

Comment: @user3491987 Upon further inspection, it revealed that you are selecting rows off the input. So, needed few changes. Please check out the edits on those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) function from numpy. Your code would then look like:

```
base=np.array([[20,30],[50,60],[70,80],[10,30]])
print(np.shape(base))
nsample=10
tmp = []
for i in range(nsample):
    id_pick = np.random.choice(np.shape(base)[0], size=(np.shape(base)[0]))
    print(id_pick)
    boot1=base[id_pick,:]
    tmp.append(boot1)
tmp = np.stack(tmp, axis=-1)
print(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Divakar 's answer, if you already know the shape of this 2D-array, you can treat it as an (8,) 1D array while bootstrapping, and then reshape it:

```
    m, n = base.shape
    flatbase = np.reshape(base, (m*n,))
    idxs = np.random.choice(range(8), (numReps, m*n))
    bootflats = flatbase[idx]
    boots = np.reshape(flatbase, (numReps, m, n))
```